# Set Max Depth RGBD SLAM

Tags: slam, navigation, rgbd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, when i set the max depth it immediately returns back to full depth. Does anyone know how to limit the depth and maintain it in RGBD Slam. Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9905/set-max-depth-rgbd-slam/) by [taha016](https://answers.ros.org/users/300/taha016/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-05-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The max-depth setting only applies for saving the whole point cloud in a file.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1